# some values of a @PostMapping using postman are not affected to the database(null or 0 value)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, rest, jpa, postman

i am learning spring boot and i dont know much about Rest and hibernate so plz give me as much details about the solution as possible.thanks
some values of a @PostMapping using postman are not affected to the database(null or 0 value)
see this image below to understand the problem

[postman screenshot of null values in the returned item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DzWu.jpg)

**Item entity**

```
package tn.esprit.spring.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ItemId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private User user;
    private String ItemName;
    // @Column(columnDefinition="text")
    private String Description;
    private double Price;
    private int AvailableQuantity;
    private double shippingWeight;
    // @Transient
    // private MultipartFile Picture;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<CartItem> CartItemList;

    public Item() {
        super();
    }

    public Item(String itemName, String description, double price, int availableQuantity, double shippingWeight,
            Category category) {
        this.ItemName = itemName;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Price = price;
        this.AvailableQuantity = availableQuantity;
        this.shippingWeight = shippingWeight;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public long getItemId() {
        return ItemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(long itemId) {
        ItemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return ItemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        ItemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        Price = price;
    }

    public int getAvailableQuantity() {
        return AvailableQuantity;
    }

    public void setAvailableQuantity(int availableQuantity) {
        AvailableQuantity = availableQuantity;
    }

    public double getShippingWeight() {
        return shippingWeight;
    }

    public void setShippingWeight(double shippingWeight) {
        this.shippingWeight = shippingWeight;
    }



    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<CartItem> getCartItemList() {
        return CartItemList;
    }

    public void setCartItemList(List<CartItem> cartItemList) {
        CartItemList = cartItemList;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

**item repository**

```
package tn.esprit.spring.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import tn.esprit.spring.entities.Item;

public interface ItemRepository  extends CrudRepository<Item, Long>  {

}
```

**item service**

```
package tn.esprit.spring.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import tn.esprit.spring.entities.Item;
import tn.esprit.spring.repository.ItemRepository;

@Service
public class ItemService implements ItemServiceInterface{
    @Autowired
    ItemRepository itemrepository;
    public Item addNewItem(Item item){
        Item i=itemrepository.save(item);
        return i;
    }
}
```

**item controller**

```
package tn.esprit.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import tn.esprit.spring.entities.Item;
import tn.esprit.spring.services.ItemServiceInterface;


@RestController
public class ItemControl {
    @Autowired
    ItemServiceInterface itemservice;
    @PostMapping("/additem")
    @ResponseBody
    public Item addnewitem(@RequestBody Item item){
        return itemservice.addNewItem(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while sending request from postman, you need to name the request body entity identical with your request dto used in your controller.
Like, for your case,  change name in your postman payload of this:
`Item_name` to `ItemName`, `available_quantity` to `availableQuantity` and `shipping_weight`  to `shippingWeight` as defined in your class.
Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

i finaly found out the source of the variable names that i should use. it's from the getters in the item entity for example:
 getItemName=>itemName
 getAvailableQuantity=>availableQuantity